# missing configuration in apache to achive mutual SSL authentcaion

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, authentication, centos, openssl

After implementing a Mutual Certificate Authentication with OpenSSL and Apache Web Server on CentOS platform. I tried this scenario ( see this diagram ):

> ---
>
> ```
>                         ----------
>                        |  Root CA  |    // Self-Signed Certificate
>                         ----------
>                      |                 |     
>                 ----------          ----------
>               |  SiteA CA  |       |  SiteB CA  |  //Two Different Intermediate CAs
>                 ----------           ----------
>                |          |                |          |
>             -------    -------            -------     -------
>          | Server1 | | Client1 |        | Server2 | | Client2 | 
>             -------    -------            -------     -------
> ```
>
> ---

So I have a different sites with different domains, e.g.:

```
www.siteA.com  
www.siteB.com
```

After putting `rootca.crt` in browser and `client1.crt` which signed by 
siteA CA, I had a big problem! Client1 whose certificate is signed by SiteCA1 can enter to both sites A & B ! and that's totally mistaken. 
How could I do it right?

Answer (score 0):

I posted an [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34897/configure-ssl-mutual-two-way-authentication) to a question in [SEC.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) that described in detail how to implement SSL mutual authentication.

In short, you could do better if you create client certs keeping in mind that there must be a way for your servers to distinguish between clients, to be able to restrict access to the sites based on the previous premise.

Choose the appropriate piece of information stored in the x509 structure of the client certificate for your purpose. Take a look at the Apache online [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire).